# matplotlib ticks in all ImageGrid axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization

Is there a way to show ticks in all x axis in an ImageGrid plot?

For example, in my output I get ticks only on the bottom row. I would like to have ticks also in the top row (data range is not necessarily the same)

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(24, 14))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,          
                 nrows_ncols=(2,4),
                 axes_pad=0.5,
                 share_all=False,
                 cbar_location="right",
                 cbar_mode="single",
                 cbar_size="5%",
                 cbar_pad=0.25,
                 )
adjustment = len(grid)
for i, j in enumerate(distance_matrices):
    im = plot_distance_matrix(distance_matrices[j],fechas[j],titulos[i], grid[i])
    im = plot_distance_matrix(distance_matrices_d[j],fechas_d[j],titulos_d[i], grid[i+int(0.5*adjustment)])

grid[-1].cax.colorbar(im)
grid[-1].cax.toggle_label(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set the parameter label_mode = "all"

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(24, 14))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,          
                 nrows_ncols=(2,4),
                 axes_pad=0.5,
                 share_all=False,
                 cbar_location="right",
                 cbar_mode="single",
                 cbar_size="5%",
                 cbar_pad=0.25,
                 label_mode="all")
adjustment = len(grid)
for i, j in enumerate(distance_matrices):
    im = plot_distance_matrix(distance_matrices[j],fechas[j],titulos[i], grid[i])
    im = plot_distance_matrix(distance_matrices_d[j],fechas_d[j],titulos_d[i], grid[i+int(0.5*adjustment)])

grid[-1].cax.colorbar(im)
grid[-1].cax.toggle_label(True)
plt.show()
```